# Intel i7-12700 12 cores, but only 4 cores seem to be usable on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, dell, intel-cpu

I'm running parallel jobs on Ubuntu 22.04 with Intel i7-12700 (8p+4e=12 cores). The name of the executable is `pimpleFoam`, 6 executables are running simultaneously with each using 2 cores, totaling up to 12 cores. But only 4 cores seem to be used in CPU graph, and each process seems to use 33% of the CPU capacity in `top` output:

[image]

[image]

In the BIOS settings, "Multi-Core Support" is set to "All Cores" (which is 8) and "Multiple Atom Cores" is set to "All Cores" (which is 4).

s-tui output while I'm using 10 processes:
[image: s-tui output]

Cores seem to work (although I'm not sure) but graphing tools do not show the usage properly.

I can't make sense of this situation. How can I check the **actual** CPU usage?

PC: Dell OptiPlex 7000 (https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000200626/dell-optiplex-7000-desktops-system-guide?lwp=rt)

Processor link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134591/intel-core-i712700-processor-25m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: See if the information in [this Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218195) helps and/or provides some ways to investigate.

Comment: Run this command  `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and tell me what it outputs.